# Как получить ориентацию картинки на php?

Tags: php

Как на `php`, можно получить ориентацию картинки ( например: ориентация картинки горизонтальная , вертикальная, квадратная )?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну для этого сначала нужно, получить ширину и высоту картинки, при помощи функции `getimagesize ()`, а потом уже сравнить ширину и высоту.

```
$foto = "hummer.jpg"; 

echo '<img src = "'.$foto.'" />';
echo "<br>";

// получаем массив, содержащий размеры и тип изображения 
$size = getimagesize ("$foto"); 

$flag = array(
    1=>'GIF', 
    2=>'JPG', 
    3=>'PNG', 
    4=>'SWF', 
    5=>'PSD', 
    6=>'BMP', 
    7=>'TIFF(байтовый порядок intel)', 
    8=>'TIFF(байтовый порядок motorola)', 
    9=>'JPC', 
    10=>'JP2', 
    11=>'JPX'
);

/// == Проверяем высоту и ширину фото ==  ///

$height_img = $size[0]; // Высота картинки
$width_img = $size[1];  // Ширина картинки

 if ($height_img == $width_img)
   {echo "Квадратная";}
 elseif ($height_img > $width_img)
   {echo "Горизонтальная";}
 else
   {echo "Вертикальная";};

/// == Для примера что выводит функция getimagesize() ==  ///

echo "<br><br>";

echo "Ширина: " . $size[0] .'<br>'; 
echo "Высота: " . $size[1] .'<br>'; 
echo "Тип изображения: " . $flag[$size[2]] .'<br>'; 
echo "Ширина и Высота: " . $size[3] .'<br>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Ориентация и размерность сторон не всегда связаны, если что...
Если есть EXIF данные в картинке, можно попытаться из них определять:

```
$file = 'path_to/image.jpg';
$exif = exif_read_data($file);

if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
    switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
        case 3:
            $image = imagerotate($image, 180, 0);
            break;

        case 6:
            $image = imagerotate($image, -90, 0);
            break;

        case 8:
            $image = imagerotate($image, 90, 0);
            break;
    }
}
```